# File.delete() return false?

Tags: java

Firstly I explain the architecture then I will come up to real Problem..

I am working with 3 tier Architecture. I completely designed DL, BL along with their test cases.
BL gets data from DL and then BL populate their own Data Structure. Add() and Update(), Getter method() are Provided in BL and DL and Customer.data will get generated for storing Customer's data when DL's add method run.

When BL's Add() method runs then firstly datastructures will get Populated then DL will get updated then Datastructures in BL get updated with new Entity.

In DL when I add a customer and then update it then it works fine.

[image: DL testCases]

"BUT when i add a customer in BL and the update it then getter methods is not working in BL" and I am unable to add new customer.

[image: BL testCases]

Note: BL use DL'S update method.

Somehow in DL's Update method file.delete() returns true when I run add, update within Test Cases folder in DL
but file.delete() returns false when I run add, update method within BL test cases folder.

I close the stream associated with file and file is not in use by other program and I check the permission.. But I don't get what the problem is

## Here is Code of Update()

This method checks if the code exists if code exists then checks if name exists.. if exists then it throws exception..
After validation is done;  This method copies the content of original file to temporary file along with customer and then copies the content of temp file to original file.

```
//........... Code
while(randomAccessFile.getFilePointer()<randomAccessFile.length()) 
{
vCode=Integer.parseInt(randomAccessFile.readLine());
vName=randomAccessFile.readLine();
vOpeningBalance=Integer.parseInt(randomAccessFile.readLine());
vOpeningBalanceType=randomAccessFile.readLine().charAt(0);
if(vCode==customerDTOInterface.getCode()) 
{ 
access=1;
pos=randomAccessFile.getFilePointer(); randomAccessFile.seek(0);

while(randomAccessFile.getFilePointer()<randomAccessFile.length()) 
{
code=Integer.parseInt(randomAccessFile.readLine());
vName=randomAccessFile.readLine(); randomAccessFile.readLine();
randomAccessFile.readLine();
if(vName.equalsIgnoreCase(customerDTOInterface.getName())) 
{ 
throw new DAOException(vName + " exists with code as : " + code); 
} 
}

randomAccessFile.seek(pos);
trandomAccessFile.writeBytes(vCode+"\n"+customerDTOInterface.getName()
+"\n"+customerDTOInterface.getOpeningBalance()+"\n"+
customerDTOInterface.getOpeningBalanceType()+"\n");
} 
else 
{
trandomAccessFile.writeBytes(vCode+"\n"+vName+"\n"+vOpeningBalance+
"\n"+vOpeningBalanceType+"\n");
} 
} 
if(access==0)
{
trandomAccessFile.close();
tfile.delete();
throw new DAOException("Invalid Code DAO");
}
randomAccessFile.close();
trandomAccessFile.seek(0); 
file.delete();             //Delete Returns False here
.......... //More Code
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide the relevant code snippets here.

Otherwise, it's hard to tell for sure what happens but in a general `file.delete` usually doesn't work because of 
permissions issue or alternatively if someone already holds a handle associated with the file (for Windows).

Since you're on Windows, the second problem is more likely the case, and the chances are that it's your own application.